# How to calculate area of these overlapping rings?

Tags: geometry, 3d, spheres, spherical-geometry

I want to calculate the surface area of what the brown paint stripes cover on the sphere. $r = 5$ cm.

[image]

Comment: How wide are the rings?

Comment: Just imagine they are 0 mm thick and located right on the sphere (same width as the sphere), so I basiclly want the area of the circle that they cover

Comment: No, the width, not the thickness.

Comment: Are the rings similar to paint - do they hug the surface of the ball? Or are they more like a slice of a cylinder with the same radius of the ball?

Comment: @jwc845 They are like paint, sorry for the lack of details. I probbably should just have excluded they whole ring part

Comment: @DenFulaAnkungen Are you expecting an answer in terms of the width of the ring (say $w$)? I know they have no thickness, but the "paint stripes" shown have a width. You should edit your question with these answers to make it more clear. Many people don't read the comments.

Comment: It seems you are looking for an answer to a question like what is the area of the surface of the Earth between latitude $5^\circ$ N and latitude $5^\circ$ S for each ring, and then we have to subtract the area where the rings overlap.  But the answer would be different if we were asked for the area between latitudes $10^\circ$ N and $10^\circ$ S, right?  That is why everyone is asking about the width of the brown rings.  How is it specified?  What is the value?

Comment: I agree with saulspatz. I'm sure one could create a generic formula, but we would need to know more about how the width of the ring is parameterized or the specific value in this instance of the problem.

Comment: You should answer to saulspatz who asked you a question almost a day ago. Besides, surface area of a ring can be computed very efficiently (in $cm^2$, not $cm^3$, I assume) by using the equivalence with the surface on a tangent cylinder. See for that http://www.matematicasvisuales.com/english/html/geometry/space/sphereCylinderAxial.html

Answer (score 1):

In short, $A = 2\left(\frac{\theta}{360} \cdot 4 \pi r^2\right) - \frac{\theta}{360}\left(\frac{\theta}{360} \cdot 4 \pi r^2\right)$.

Really what's trying to be found is part of the surface area. The surface area of a sphere is $A = 4 \pi r^2$. To work that out you'd need to provide the radius.

But we're only interested in a fraction of the area, the thickness of the brown rings. To relate the thickness to the radius, imagine the sphere as just a circle with the same radius as the sphere (you can think of it as cutting right down the middle of the sphere). Then the thickness will be some part of the circumference. To find a fraction of the circumference, or in other words the length of an arc, you can do (assuming degrees) $\text{arc length} = \frac{\theta}{360} \pi d$. The same can be applied to the surface area of a sphere, giving $A = \frac{\theta}{360} \cdot 4 \pi r^2$.

This is done twice since there are two rings. However, there is an overlap. You can think of this similarly as the whole ring. We're only interested in a short part of the ring, more specifically a part of the ring that's the size of the width, in other words, we're interested in a fraction of the ring, the same fraction's the thickness.
So we need to subtract $\frac{\theta}{360}$ times the ring's area from the total.

So in short, $A = 2\left(\frac{\theta}{360} \cdot 4 \pi r^2\right) - \frac{\theta}{360}\left(\frac{\theta}{360} \cdot 4 \pi r^2\right)$.

To demonstrate an example where the radius is 10 units and the ring is 5 units, first rearrange the arc length equation to find $\theta$:

\begin{align}
\text{arc length} &= \frac{\theta}{360} \pi d \\
\theta &= 360\left(\frac{\text{arc length}}{\pi d}\right) \\
&= 360\left(\frac{5}{\pi (10 \div 2)}\right)\\
&= \frac{360}{\pi} ^\circ
\end{align}

Then substitute:

\begin{align}
A &= 2\left(\frac{\theta}{360} \cdot 4 \pi r^2\right) - \frac{\theta}{360}\left(\frac{\theta}{360} \cdot 4 \pi r^2\right)\\
&= 2\left(\frac{\frac{360}{\pi}}{360} \cdot 4 \pi 5^2\right) - \frac{\frac{360}{\pi}}{360}\left(\frac{\frac{360}{\pi}}{360} \cdot 4 \pi 5^2\right)\\
&= 168.1 \dots\\
&\approx 168 \text{ units}^2
\end{align}